# What is the point of Convert.ToDateTime(bool)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I was doing some type conversion routines last night for a system I am working on.  One of the conversions involves turning string values into their DateTime equivalents.

While doing this, I noticed that the Convert.ToDateTime() method had an overload which accepted a boolean parameter.

First question?  Under what circumstances could this ever be useful?

I went a little further and tried to execute the method in QuickWatch.  Either way ( true or false ), the routine returns an InvalidCastException.

Second question?  Why is this method even here?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers, guys.  I can see how it *makes sense* from a contractual point of view, but it does seem odd that the core framework includes methods that:-

- Can never work
- Worse, will actually throw an exception when someone tries to call it.

It's a bit like someone making a car loaded with controls that actively stop your vehicle from working when used.

Comment: not only "stop from working", actually make it crash :-)

Comment: Eric Lippert wont be too proud of this work from the BCL team. According to him every feature is unimplemented by default and implemented only if need arises subject to cost/demand. Apparently someone was too rich in BCL :) Practically of no use for clients..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes sense because `ToDateTime` is part of the `IConvertible` interface implemented by `bool`. If you look in reflector you will see that it throws an `InvalidCastException`.

**Update** (from `Convert`):

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(bool value)
{
    return ((IConvertible) value).ToDateTime(null);
}
```

Comment: But: this is a static method which can't be part of an interface. So this isn't logical at all.

Comment: Still: there is no use to implement a static method which shouldn't be called. The static method is statically bound by the compiler, there is nothing dynamic here and there is no use for this method.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger I think it makes sense. Convert contains convenience method to call all conversions on all types that implement `IConvertible`. From an API design point of view I think it would be weirder (or at least equally weird) if it had been left out.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's there for completeness and that you get an explicit InvalidCastException when calling Convert.ToDateTime with an object that is a bool.

If you look at all the members of Convert, you can see that overloads have been included to accept all the basic types for conversion to each of the other basic types, with InvalidCastExceptions being thrown when there is no sensible conversion.

I guess they thought this would be more meaningful than just not having the overloads there at all.

Comment: I think, this is the only explanation for this. The *thought" it would be better to make it complete. But actually, there is no use of it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely, [**most**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx) of the overloads are invalid and will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

It has to implement *all* of the casts as it implements `IConvertible` and this is the only way to do it correctly.

Comment: These are static methods, they do not implement any interfaces. So the question remains: why are these methods there?