# Convert TO DateTIme in C#

Tags: c#, casting

As all we know we know we use `Convert.ToDateTime()` function for converting value to datetime.

But when I was seeking in this method, I found it will convert from type of the following value.

- bool
- byte
- Char
- DateTIme
- Decimal
- double
- Float
- Int
- Long
  etc...

But from among of this how it will convert to **DateTime** from **bool** type?

I.E:- `Convert.ToDateTime(true);`

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? What should `true` / `false` convert to?

Comment: Have you considered.. Running this code? You'll get an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Well if you check it says *Calling this method always throws System.InvalidCastException.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the point of Convert.ToDateTime(bool)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689572/what-is-the-point-of-convert-todatetimebool)

Answer (score 2):

> But from among of this how it will convert to DateTime from bool type?

It doesn't:

> Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx).

These will always Throw an invalid cast operation

`DateTime, String, and Object` are the only three types that don't (object probably stil can)

[More Documentation (See Bottom)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx)

> An InvalidCastException is thrown for the following conversions:
> Conversions from DateTime to any other type except String.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt. It will throw `InvalidCastException`.

Something like this is what people do:-

```
DateTime d;
bool isDate = DateTime.TryParse(argument, out d);
```

Answer (score 0):

It implement IConvertible which contains ALL the cast. It's is there for completeness rather than usability. And as what the previous answers tell you, it throws a InvalidCastException

Comment: I can understand why the method call `((IConvertible)true).ToDateTime(culture);` needs to exist and throw an exception, because of the infrastructure chosen. But they did not _have_ to give all those `static` method overloads which always throw, did they? It seems crazy. But your answer is correct, of course.